# How to find the longest list in a pandas series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to print the longest list in a series and display top 10 lengths and the corresponding lists.

I tried to do

```
df["listoflists"].value_counts()
```

But it only prints the count of the keys but not the length of the keys i.e. lists. I also tried

```
print(df["listoflists"].applymap(len).idxmax(axis=1))
```

But getting an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'` How can this be solved?

Comment: You could just use `.apply()` here: `df['listoflists'].apply(len).idxmax()`. AFAIK `.applymap()` works only with a full DataFrame.

Comment: @mechanical_meat But it only displays a number (length). I would like the length and the corresponding value displayed!

Comment: Ok, so I think you should assign that length back to the DataFrame e.g.: `df['len'] = df['listoflists'].apply(len)` then you can groupby that column and also do your top 10 thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you're having following dataframe :

```
values = [['a','a'], ['a','b','b','d','e'],
         ['a','b','b','a'], ['a','b','c','a'],
         ['a','b','b'],['a','b','b']

df = pd.DataFrame({'listoflists' :values })
```

For the longest list, you can try :

```
max(df.listoflists, key=len)
```

and for the top *n* list, you can try (n = 3 in this example) :

```
df['count'] = df.listoflists.map(len)
df.nlargest(3, ['count'])
```

Comment: Haha, it's been a minute since I've used `pandas`. I like your use of `.nlargest()` here instead of what I did.

Answer (score 2):

I'll show you how to do this on just some random data:

```
# easy random data 
df = pd.DataFrame({'listoflists':[[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]}) 

# assign back to DataFrame so we can manipulate 
df['len'] = df['listoflists'].apply(len)

# then to get top N:
N = 1
df.sort_values(['len'],ascending=False).groupby(['len']).transform(min).head(N)
```